# How to copy an existing form from an organization to other organization in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to copy an existing form from an organization to another organization in Cognito Forms in order to set a different email address to the form. How can I do this?

Comment: I am a developer for Cognito Forms. This is a feature we plan to implement in a future release. You can follow our progress on our Idea Board (https://trello.com/c/3rIO1QeU).

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this in Cognito Forms in two different ways:

1. If you are a member of both organizations, you now have the option to copy forms from other organizations when creating a new form.  Just select New Form - Copy Existing Form.
2. You can share your form designs with anyone by enabling sharing under Form Settings.  This will provide you with a link that anyone can use to create forms based on your form design.